# Calculations in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to get some data from a database. In that I want to do some calculations:

For every day I have 2 different datapoints. What I want is to add a new datapoint which is the sum of the two datapoints.

In my example I want to code the following task:

for every 'Date' I want a new datapoint (let's call it category3) which is the sum af 'Data' from 'category1' and 'category2'. My code:

```
 SELECT   
     [Date], [category], [Data]
 FROM 
     [ ... ]
 WHERE 
     category IN ('category1', 'category2')
 ORDER BY
     AsOfDate
```

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result. (As formatted text.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just want a simple `group by` query with a `where`?

```
 select [Date], SUM(Data)
 from [ ... ]
 Where category  in ('category1','category2')
 group by AsOfDate
```

Comment: @k.dkhk . . . That is not the question you asked.  If you have another question, ask it as a question, along with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT  [Date],
        [category],
        [Data]
FROM [ ... ]
WHERE category  IN ('category1','category2')
UNION ALL
SELECT  [Date],
        'category3',
        SUM([Data])
FROM [ ... ]
WHERE category  IN ('category1','category2')
GROUP BY [Date];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT t1.[Date],
        t1.[Data], 
        t2.[Data],
        t1.[Data] + t2.[Data] as [category3]
 FROM [ ... ] t1 inner join [ ... ] t2 on t1.[Date] = t2.[Date] and t1.category = 'category1' and t2.category = 'category2'
 order by AsOfDate
```